# Where are the rules for Ride skill and beasts?

Tags: books, star-wars-saga-edition

The ride skill (not pilot) in SAGA edition core rule books states:

> Use this skill to ride any kind of mount, such as a tauntaun, dewback or bantha

Obviously these are types of beasts, as opposed to vehicles as listed in the vehicle chapter. The rules for actually riding beasts appear to be completely missing though — so where are the rules (if any exist)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. What rules are you asking for? Ride rules for vehicles? Ride skills for beasts? Are the rules for riding beasts missing completely?

Comment: The Ride skill has a bunch of applications, most of which don't have rules over when they would be used. The actual rules for being a mounted character on a beast however are missing.

Comment: I've edited your question clarify what you're asking about then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, **The Unknown Regions** page 28 has the rules.